# Target JRE in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java

How should I change Target JRE in Eclipse. I was earlier using jdk1.7, now I want to use JDK 1.6. But while running my java program I am getting Unsupported Class Version Error. Is there some setting that I need to do before using jdk1.6. How should i make sure that my eclipse compiles and runs only in jdk1.6.

Answer (score 8):

If the project has been already started with JDK 1.6, you have to change also the project level settings, so :

```
Project ---> Properties ---> Java Compiler : set compliance level and Source compatibility to 1.7

Project ---> Properties ---> Java Build Path ---> Libraries ---> and change the JRE system library to 1.7
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to : Windows -> preferences -> Java -> compilers -> JDK compliance
2. Change installed JDK version accordingly.

Comment: @programmer_1- already done that. still getting unsupported Class Version error.

Comment: @RohitElayathu That's because something you're using in your code is only compatible with a different JRE than the JRE you are targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I had troubles with the Eclipse preferences, so if nothing seems to help anymore I try the following.

Switch to the Navigator view, open your project and the .settings folder.
Check for the following files and check/update the following settings (depending on the project type there might be different files). I just opened a maven web project.

**file org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs:**

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
```

**file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
   <installed facet="jst.java" version="6.0"/>
   ...
 </faceted-project>
```

**file .classpath (in app root, not .settings directory)**

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
```

Basicly you can search for 1.7 and 7.0 in the enclosing project, to check/update the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the target ***JRE*** with the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) when compiling!  I am not sure how to achieve that using the Eclipse preferences, but is simple to do when using the Oracle Java SDK & compiling using Ant (Eclipse can run Ant scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Go to

`Window -> Preferences ->`

Now `Select and Expand Java`

Now `Select option Installed JREs`

and now you can add new JRE to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should right-click the project and set the `Java Build Path` to use the 1.6 JDK and at the `Java Compiler` settings set the compliance level to 1.6.

If you don't have the 1.6 option, you probably didn't add the 1.6JDK to the `Installed JRE`s list. To do this go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` and add it there.

Comment: @Matyas- already done all that. But when I am trying to run my program its giving unsupported Class Version error.