# Why am I not able to use default method in interface?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package p;

public interface t1 {
     int t = 6;

     default void method_default(){
         System.out.println("default method");
     }    
}
```

Why am I getting these errors in my eclipse IDE after writing the above code?

- Abstract methods do not specify a body
- Illegal modifier for the interface method method_default; only public & abstract are permitted
- Syntax error on token "default", delete this token

I am using JDK 14.0.1 and JRE 1.8.0_251.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are (or perhaps _eclipse is_) using the versions you specified?

Comment: The syntax is fine. Seems like an Eclipse problem. Possibly because it's configured to target a lower version than 8. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092284/target-jre-in-eclipse

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? And why are you using Java 14 for your JDK and then specifying a Java 8 runtime? I will note that your posted code compiles fine on my copy of eclipse.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's perfectly valid to do that.

Comment: There seems some setting issue in eclipse, I have tried it in IntelliJ and it works as expected.

Comment: @Michael Sure. But eclipse uses its' own compiler (unless OP is using maven or some other external build tool). So I'm really just trying to work out what OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax issue as long as the compiler version is 1.8 or above.

First check **Installed JREs**

[image]

and then check the **JDK Compliance** in your eclipse and apply the required version if any of them is set at a lower version.

[image]

Comment: highest compiler compliance level I have is 1.7, is it fine and if not then how to increase it?

Comment: The concept of default interface was introduced with Java8 and therefore a compiler of lower version (e.g. 1.7) won't recognize the syntax. If you've not been able to set it so far, check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version) article for step by step instructions.

Comment: @AdityaPrakash *highest compiler compliance level I have is 1.7* [What version of eclipse are you using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544304/why-am-i-not-able-to-use-default-method-in-interface#comment108866075_61544304) Answer by implication - Kepler or earlier. Luna (released June 2014) added official Java 8 support (there is a patched version of [Kepler](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/sr2-java8-patches) available). But now is a great time to upgrade eclipse. And Java 11 is the current LTS release. Do you have a compelling reason to target Java 8?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am using the Kepler version.