# lambda expression not supporting in stream().allMatch() / .anyMatch() method

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

I'm not getting why JAVA 1.8 is not supporting the lambda expression in stream().filter() / allMatch() / anyMatch()

for example :

[ERROR snippet from eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTDhM.png)

```
import java.util.*; 
  
class GFG { 
      
    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
          
    // Creating a list of Integers 
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6, 12, 20); 
      
    // Check if all elements of stream 
    // are divisible by 3 or not using  
    // Stream allMatch(Predicate predicate) 
    boolean answer = list.stream().allMatch(n-> n % 3 ==0); 
      
    // Displaying the result 
    System.out.println(answer); 
} 
}
```

I'm getting errors in eclipse as "Syntax error on token "-", -- expected" and red lines below 'n'.
Please help me to understand and resolve this issue.

#NOTE: I'm using eclipse 3.8, JAVA 8 (1.8.0_271)

Comment: Eclipse 3.8 is ancient  (8 years and 15 releases old) and doesn't understand lambda expressions, use a modern version of Eclipse such as the current 2020-09.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll use the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem to compile and run in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php
Which runs Java 1.8.0_141.
Check if the target run time in eclipse is set to java 8.

You can use [Target JRE in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092284/target-jre-in-eclipse) as an example.

Comment: The problem is Eclipse's built in Java compiler ('ecj'). The version in Eclipse 3.8 is so old it does not understand lambda expressions.